# How to set the JFreeChart X axis data titles?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jfreechart

Attached my code snippet here, I am using `XYStepChart` from chart factory. The x-axis scale at output for the code is being displayed in scale of eg: `05:30:00:00`, `05:30:00:01`, `05:30:00:00`. But I need in values like 1,2,3,4.

```
package org.jfree.chart.demo;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;
public class XYStepChartDemo 
{
private ChartFrame frame = null;
private void displayChart() {
    if (this.frame == null) {
        final String title = "Trace";
        final String xAxisLabel = "Tasks";
        final String yAxisLabel = "Amplitude";
        final XYDataset data = createStepXYDataset();
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYStepChart(
            title,
            xAxisLabel, yAxisLabel,
            data,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            true,   // legend
            true,   // tooltips
            false   // urls
        );
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(216, 216, 216));
        final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        plot.getRenderer().setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(2.0f));
        plot.getRenderer().setSeriesStroke(1, new BasicStroke(2.0f));
        this.frame = new ChartFrame("Plan Comparison", chart);
        this.frame.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.positionFrameRandomly(this.frame);
        this.frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    else {
        this.frame.setVisible(true);
        this.frame.requestFocus();
    }
   }

 public static XYDataset createStepXYDataset() {
 final XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Series 2");
 series1.add(0, 5);
 series1.add(1, 0);
 series1.add(2, 0);
 series1.add(3, 0);
 series1.add(4, 0);
 series1.add(5, 5);
 series1.add(6, 0);
 series1.add(7, 0);
 series1.add(8, 0);
 final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
 dataset.addSeries(series1);
 return dataset;
  }
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final XYStepChartDemo demo = new XYStepChartDemo();
    demo.displayChart();

   }

   }
```

[image: Output looks like x-axis in some time format, i need only in values like 1, 2, 3, 4 etc to be displayed]

Comment: can someone please help

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117785).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ChartFactory.createXYStepChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.2027) uses a `DateAxis` for the domain, so your `XYSeries` ordinates are interpreted as seconds since the [Java epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Computing). You can either,

- Use `setDateFormatOverride()` to format the values as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22264230/230513).
- Use `setDomainAxis()` on the `XYPlot` to substitute a `NumberAxis` for the domain, also suggested [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117785#p180477); use integer tick units, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8399520/230513).

  ```
  NumberAxis domain = new NumberAxis(xAxisLabel);
  domain.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
  plot.setDomainAxis(domain);
  ```

[image]